# Repeating a texture in a Texture Region

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

I have a single texture map that contains 64 different textures (think Minecraft) which gets split up using the Texture Region function.

How do repeat a texture that uses the Texture Region function?  I cant multiply the texture size (so * 3 would repeat it 3 times) because it will just pick up the next textures in the texture map (so 9 in total).

```
texture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);
MeshBuilder.regions = TextureRegion.split(texture, 64, 64)

var cube: Model
cubes = Array()
for (x in 0..7) {
   for (y in 0..7) {

         modelBuilder.begin()
         val mpb = modelBuilder.part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, (VertexAttributes.Usage.Position or VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal or VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates).toLong(), Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.BLUE)))
         mpb.setUVRange(MeshBuilder.regions[x][y])
         mpb.box(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
         cube = modelBuilder.end()
         cube.meshes.get(0).scale(Constants.cubeSize, Constants.cubeSize, Constants.cubeSize)
         cubes.add(cube)
      }
   }
```

Comment: Your question is very weird and unclear: "How do then repeat that single texture which is actually just a position on the main texture?". That just doesn't make sense. Please carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/ and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Understood I will try and improve it

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16618766/3177465